# Missing logic in sudoku puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image]

I got stuck in the given sudoku puzzle. I can't find any logic to put a number in the empty block. I am playing classic sudoku Android puzzle app.

Maybe it's a XY wing or empty rectangle or any other logic.

Comment: 5 in column 9 is placed.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than the answers. In column 9, there must always be one 4 and one 9 no matter the order, so r4c9 must be a 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to proceed

> Notice that in column 8 (c8), the 5 must be in the lower box (r7 or r9) which means that r5c8 cannot contain a 5 and so r5c3 must contain 5. This in turn implies that the highlighted box must contain **4**.
>  Also notice in column 9 that there is only one possibility for 5 (in row 4).
>  You should be able to progress from here.

Comment: Why is it that in c8, the 5 must be in the lower box? EDIT: Ah, because the lower box needs to have 5, and is only possible there. Ok.

Answer (score 1):

> A 5 or 9 at row 8, column 5 implies a [non-unique solution](http://hodoku.sourceforge.net/en/tech_ur.php#u1), so 8,5 is 4. To get to the highlighted square, 4,7 becomes 9 and 7,8 cannot be 9. This makes a non-unique corner that forces 4,3 to be 9. 5,3 becomes 5 and we find a 4 at 3,7.

> In addition, column 9 has a 4,9 group, so 9,4 is a 5. This forces 4,1 to 4, 9,1 to 5 and 7,3 to 4.

Of course, the answer from [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino) is also correct, I only add these as they are slightly more direct.